# Добавление произвольных тегов в форму Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

При использовании данного кода, hidden поле "city" в используемой форме затирается. Помогите разрешить конфликт, необходимо чтобы поле "city" и добавленные поля, приведенные ниже, не затирали друг друга. На данном этапе работы, в тег "p" в форме попадают мои поля. Если не вызывать wpcf7_add_form_tag, то в тег "p" попадает поле city вместе с значением города, еще до отправки формы.  Во всех шаблонах форма вызывается подобным образом:

```
  <?= do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="111" title="blabla"]') ?>
```

В корне темы создаю functions.php и добавляю следующее содержание:

```
 <?php
function hidden() {

//Поля формы
$source = isset($_REQUEST['utm_source']) ? $_REQUEST['utm_source'] : '' ;
$term = isset($_REQUEST['utm_term']) ? $_REQUEST['utm_term'] : '' ;
$campaign = isset($_REQUEST['utm_campaign']) ? $_REQUEST['utm_campaign'] : '' ;
$medium = isset($_REQUEST['utm_medium']) ? $_REQUEST['utm_medium'] : '' ;
$content = isset($_REQUEST['utm_content']) ? $_REQUEST['utm_content'] : '';

$html = '<input type="hidden" name="source" class="source" id="utm_source" value="'.$source.'" />';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="term" class="term" id="utm_term" value="'.$term.'" />';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="campaign" class="campaign" id="utm_campaign" value="'.$campaign.'" />';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="medium" class="medium" id="utm_medium" value="'.$medium.'" />';
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="content" class="term" id="utm_content" value="'.$content.'" />';
    return $html;
}

    wpcf7_add_form_tag('hidden', 'hidden', false);

?>
```

Поле city
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема?

++Было найдено решение в лоб. Я просто в конце вставил следующее:

```
$html .= '<input type="hidden" name="city" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-hidden js-city-input" value="" />';
```

Дело в том, что город все равно попадает по классу `.js-city-input` подобным образом:

```
    function updateDeliveryInfo(){
    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
    if(geolocation.city){
        $('.js-city-input').val(geolocation.city);
        $('.js-city').text(geolocation.city);
        $('.city').show();
    }
}
```

Если не найдется решения лучше, оставлю этот костыль. По факту в шаблоне формы явно указано поле city, сейчас оно оттуда игнорируется и прописывается вручную.

Comment: Исправьте, пожалуйста, вопрос, чтобы его можно было понять. "поле city в используемой форме затирается." - "необходимо чтобы поле city в форме затирается". Ну так уже затирается - в чем вопрос? Кроме того, в коде никакого city нет.

Comment: city попадает в форму с помощью geo_ip.

Comment: А что у вас при вызове функции в аргументе $tag?

Comment: В данный момент я поменял функцию. И вызываю ее без аргументов

Comment: В шаблоне самой формы в cf, в панели администратора wordpress поле city вставляется следующим образом   [hidden city class:js-city-input]. И оно так вставляется для всех форм(а их достаточно много). Чтобы вручную не дублировать код, во все формы добавляются input из функции hidden

Comment: Я посмотрел код wpcf7_add_form_tag(), там тег (первый аргумент) добавляется только в том случае, если он ещё не существует. Т.е. нельзя два раза добавить 'hidden'. Это объясняет, почему city не попадает в форму. При этом не видно ограничений на названия тегов. Попробуйте так сделать: wpcf7_add_form_tag('my-hidden', 'hidden', false);

Comment: К сожалению ваш вариант оставляет только поле city. Мои поля в форму не попадают.

Comment: OK, значит, теги с произвольным именем нельзя. Сделаю позже.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78012/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-bumerang37).

Comment: Зачем вам этот костыль, когда я дал вам ответ, построенный на классической замене хука.

Comment: Я пока не проверил работоспособность вашего варианта. Попробовав ваш вариант в чистом виде, то есть скопировав код в functions.php, код не сработал. Разобравшись отпишусь, пока не могу сказать ничего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде `wpcf7_add_form_tag()` тег (первый аргумент) добавляется только в том случае, если он ещё не существует. Т.е. нельзя два раза добавить 'hidden'. Это объясняет, почему city не попадает в форму.

Чтобы использовать добаление ваших полей через hidden тег, надо добавить следующий код в functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'my_wpcf7_add_form_tag_hidden', 0 );

function my_wpcf7_add_form_tag_hidden() {
    remove_action( 'wpcf7_init', 'wpcf7_add_form_tag_hidden' );

    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'hidden',
        'my_wpcf7_hidden_form_tag_handler',
        array(
            'name-attr'      => true,
            'display-hidden' => true,
        )
    );
}

function my_wpcf7_hidden_form_tag_handler( $tag ) {
    $source   = isset( $_REQUEST['utm_source'] ) ? $_REQUEST['utm_source'] : '';
    $term     = isset( $_REQUEST['utm_term'] ) ? $_REQUEST['utm_term'] : '';
    $campaign = isset( $_REQUEST['utm_campaign'] ) ? $_REQUEST['utm_campaign'] : '';
    $medium   = isset( $_REQUEST['utm_medium'] ) ? $_REQUEST['utm_medium'] : '';
    $content  = isset( $_REQUEST['utm_content'] ) ? $_REQUEST['utm_content'] : '';

    $html = '<input type="hidden" name="source" class="source" id="utm_source" value="' . $source . '" />';

    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="term" class="term" id="utm_term" value="' . $term . '" />';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="campaign" class="campaign" id="utm_campaign" value="' . $campaign . '" />';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="medium" class="medium" id="utm_medium" value="' . $medium . '" />';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="content" class="term" id="utm_content" value="' . $content . '" />';

    if ( empty( $tag->name ) ) {
        return $html;
    }

    $atts = array();

    $class         = wpcf7_form_controls_class( $tag->type );
    $atts['class'] = $tag->get_class_option( $class );
    $atts['id']    = $tag->get_id_option();

    $value         = (string) reset( $tag->values );
    $value         = $tag->get_default_option( $value );
    $atts['value'] = $value;

    $atts['type'] = 'hidden';
    $atts['name'] = $tag->name;
    $atts         = wpcf7_format_atts( $atts );

    $html .= sprintf( '<input %s />', $atts );

    return $html;
}
```

Код протестирован. Результат можете увидеть на [этой странице](http://test.kagg.eu/contact/) тестового сайта.